# MSBuild custom task "Hello World" walkthrough

Tags: msbuild, msbuild-task, custom-build-step

Can someone write (or link to) a walkthrough that explains *exactly* how to create a custom MSBuild task and run it during a build?  I'm looking for a custom task that inherits from `Microsoft.Build.Utilities.Task` and does only this:

```
public override bool Execute()
{
    Log.LogMessage("Hello world!");
    return true;
}
```

(I've been working on this for hours and keep getting the "The [whatever] task was not found. Check the following" message.  I think I must be missing an essential step somewhere.  If there's a clear tutorial I can follow, perhaps I'll figure out where I'm falling short.)

Comment: Are you including in a <UsingTask>?  Can you post the MSBUILD where you try to invoke along with the full class for the task?

Comment: Well, heck.  It turns out my stupid build task *was* working.  But Log.LogMessage doesn't display anything in the build window if the build verbosity is set to the default setting Minimal.  http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/msbuild/thread/9f60e577-a420-4302-ba5f-703a6cae7992

Comment: ...Unless I use the overload that lets me specify `MessageImportance.High`, and then it displays even with Minimal.

Comment: Although the OP's original need has been solved, nothing really answered the question of providing a "hello world" example. That would be really useful still.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Are you declaring your custom task in your MSBuild project file?  You need a line like this:

```
    <UsingTask AssemblyFile="C:\PathTo\MyTasks.dll" TaskName="MyTasks.HelloWord" />
```

Then MSBuild can execute your task.

Comment: I was doing that, but I didn't realize that TaskName had to be the actual class name including namespace.  That seems to be the thing that was my roadblock.

Answer (score 12):

See

1. [Best Practices For Creating Reliable Builds](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd483291.aspx) section **Creating Custom Tasks**.
2. [THE CUSTOM MSBUILD TASK COOKBOOK](https://web.archive.org/web/20200222130526/http://bartdesmet.net/blogs/bart/archive/2008/02/15/the-custom-msbuild-task-cookbook.aspx) from Bart De Smet

Comment: Thanks for this. Too many resources such as https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/task-writing?view=vs-2017 provide C# and MSBuild code but provide no information on what to do with the C# code so you can actually use it. They do not give the critical piece of information that you need to build a DLL.