# VS2010 how to make output to show counter of projects built

Tags: windows, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, csc

I have solution with very big number of projects in it and would like to see somehow progress of compilation.

As you probably know when compiling we see only those strings in Output Window  (even if it's open widely) -

```
...
_CopyAppConfigFile:
    Copying file from "app.config" to "bin\Debug\Bububu.exe.config".
CopyFilesToOutputDirectory:
  Copying file from "obj\Debug\Bububu.exe" to "bin\Debug\Bububu.exe".
  Bububu -> C:\Dev\Bububu\bin\Debug\Bububu.exe
  Copying file from "obj\Debug\Bububu.pdb" to "bin\Debug\Bububu.pdb".
```

Build succeeded.

Well, 
I'd like to see something like "Build 13/26 succeeded..." Is this possible at all?

Answer (score 2):

[EDIT]

*My mistake.  The screenshots in my answer are from Visual Studio 2012.  The line numbers are not shown in Visual Studio 2010 using this technique.*

---

You can get project build numbers for each project by setting the `MSBuild project build output verbosity` setting in `Tools/Options`.

Open `Tools\Options\Projects and Solutions\Build and Run` dialog.

Set the verbosity setting to `Detailed` as shown in the screenshot.
[image: MsBuild Verbosity setting].

When you compile the solution you'll see a project number for each project at the beginning of the line output.

[image: Project number output]

This doesn't give you the 4/12 format that you want, it's a start.

To get it closer to your desired formatting, look at creating a custom build task.

[msbuild-custom-task-hello-world-walkthrough](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5170475/msbuild-custom-task-hello-world-walkthrough)

Comment: what version of Visual Studio are you using?

Comment: 2010 Professionsal - Version 10.0.40219.1 SP1Rel (.Net Framework 4.5.50709 SP1Rel

Comment: it's interesting, but how I can view params of default - meaning not custom - build?

Comment: Open your .csproj file in a text editor.  It's really just an XML file containing instructions for the MSBuild engine.

Comment: I updated my answer.  The line numbers only work in the output window in VS 2012.